# File error: Cannot open load file, jde. How to resolve this?

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
-
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/afs/nada.kth.se/hom\
e/d99/d99-nro/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, jde

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

.emacs:

```
;; - -  - -  - -  - -  - -
;;
;;  Emacs JDE
;;

(setq load-path
       (nconc '(
                "/pkg/jde/2.1.4"
                )
                load-path))
(require 'jde)
;;  - -  - -  - -  - -  - -

;;  - -  - -  - -  - -  - -
;;
;;   Make possible to compile from inside emacs
;;   using control-c -m
;;

(global-set-key "\C-cm" 'compile)

(setq load-path (cons "/src/lang/sictus/sicstus3.5" load-path))
(autoload 'run-prolog "prolog"
"Start a Prolog sub-process." t)
(autoload 'prolog-mode "prolog"
"Major mode for editing prolog programs" t)(autoload 'prolog-menu-hook-function
"prolog-menu" t)
(add-hook 'prolog-mode-hook 'prolog-menu-hook-function)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, lisp files of JDE are in the `lisp` subdirectory. See [installation instructions](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/install.html) for more information...

P.S. instead of `(setq load-path....` it's easier to use `(add-to-list 'load-path ...)` - it will exclude duplicates & easier to read